# How to insert current date and time into logout field using php and mysql

Tags: android

i am working on File transfer via Socket, between Android devices but my application is not working properly ,after click on connect button application close unfortunately application has stopped msg displays
and error shows in console of client side code

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11553
>                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024;                     regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
>                         at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1719)
>                         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:135)
>                         at com.example.moraya.socketfileserverside1.MainActivity$ClientRxThread.run(MainActivity.java:75)
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb81c2c30
>   (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8211e88

Thanks sir

Comment: hi sir, is there any solution for my question

Comment: Please add MainActivity code to question